# How to pass parameter to custom library with codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a custom library in codeigniter, i want to pass parametere in constructor.
Any solution appriciated!

```
function __construct( $iteration_count_log2, $portable_hashes )
    {
        $this->itoa64 = 
'./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

    if ($iteration_count_log2 < 4 || $iteration_count_log2 > 31)
        $iteration_count_log2 = 8;
    $this->iteration_count_log2 = $iteration_count_log2;

    $this->portable_hashes = $portable_hashes;

    $this->random_state = microtime() . uniqid(rand(), TRUE); // removed getmypid() for compatibility reasons
}
```

Here is the code for loading library

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('PasswordHash');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html#passing-parameters-when-initializing-your-class

When initializing your library:

```
$params = array('type' => 'large', 'color' => 'red');

$this->load->library('someclass', $params);
```

Your library:

```
class Someclass {

        public function __construct($params)
        {
                echo $params['type']; // large
        }
}
```

Notice: only one parameter can come through with CI, so if you want to send multiple parameters it must be sent via one parameter as an array as shown above.